# Wordpress white screen of death using vlucas/phpdotenv, trying to load .env variables

Tags: php, wordpress, dotenv

I've setup a Wordpress site on EC2 (Amazon 2 Linux) with RDS and it's working fine. I am now trying to load environment variables from a .env file using https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv.

1. wp-config.php is in /var/www (one level up from the root html directory)
2. I ran `composer require vlucas/phpdotenv` in /var/www/, and now I have /var/www/vendor, the composer .json and .lock files.

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.1"
    }
}
```

My .env file is as follows (values redacted):

```
DB_NAME=DBNAME
DB_USER=USERNAME
DB_PASS=PASSWORD
DB_HOST=HOSTNAME
```

I have added the following to wp-config.php, at the top but then I get the dreaded Wordpress white screen of death.

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
(new \Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__))->load();
```

I've added my environment variables as below, but even if I revert back to manual entries, with the code above it displays the white screen.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', getenv('DB_NAME'));

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', getenv('DB_USER'));

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', getenv('DB_PASS'));

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', getenv('DB_HOST'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wordpress autoloading and package management won’t allow it to happen that easily. You can try something like https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer where Composer is already integrated and ready to be used alongside Wordpress Core. See the article at https://salferrarello.com/install-wordpress-with-composer/

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the white screen issue by adding if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php')) and wrapping the code in that. Now it won't recognize the database settings. Seems getenv('DB_NAME') isn't working. I've checked the .env file is correct.

Comment: Just adding 
`require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');` and `(new \Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__))->load();` to `wp-config.php` should work as long as the relative path to `./vendor/autoload.php` is correct. To access the environment variables, you should use `$_ENV['VARIABLE_NAME']` instead of `getenv('VARIABLE_NAME')` as described in the documentation of https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv. This worked perfectly fine for me with WordPress 5.8

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it, despite pulling my hair out over the last 24 hours.

```
if(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
}
if(file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
}
```

I found after searching around, that using the IF statement to check if the file and directory already exists fixed it. Both my composer and .env live one level up from the web root (/var/www/html/) so I didn't need to change that.

Also I loaded the `.env` with the code example vlucas has on his GitHub page.